# Spotlight Dictionary results no longer showing multiple languages in 10.11.3

Tags: macos, spotlight, dictionary, language

I recently did a software update on El Capitan, from 10.11.1 to 10.11.3, and now Spotlight will no longer allow look-up of foreign language words.

For example, I was able to look up "chaise" and have it show the French definition of the word. Now, it will only show the English definition or the Dutch (the latter I assume because my keyboard is set to Belgian input?). Oddly, though, if I write "chace", the Portuguese "chaçar" will show up, even though I have deselected the Portuguese Dictionary. Likewise, I will sometimes get Japanese/Korean/Chinese results.

The only way I can get the French definition of "chaise" to show up, is if I change the keyboard input to ABC-AZERTY.

I work in Italian, German, French, English, and Dutch, and it was a very useful feature to be able to look up words at a fast stroke in all of these languages, without having to go through the Dictionary app and change the look-up language manually.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have a similar problem. Only chinese shows up when I do a spotlight search. I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: No solution yet but I did find a way around it, by moving all the unused dictionaries out of /Library/Dictionaries. I put them in a separate folder in /Library (just so I could put them back in case the OS suddenly started to bug out, but I haven't had any problems so far). It works in the sense that I no longer get Chinese/Portuguese/... results, but no way to look up any other languages than the one set by my keyboard input choice.